# file directory not found error.Please help.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script.py'

Tags: python, mkdir

```py
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
    # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
    if os.path.isdir(directory,mode="w+") == False:
        os.mkdir(directory)

    # Create the new file inside of the new directory
    os.chdir(directory)
    with open(filename) as file:
        pass

    # Return the list of files in the new directory
    return os.listdir(directory)

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

My code is showing this error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\new.py", line 16, in <module>
     print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
     File "C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\new.py", line 14, in new_directory
      return os.listdir(directory)
   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 
   'PythonPrograms'
  [Finished in 0.1s]
```

i have tried by not using the mode="w+" then im getting another error..

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir(directory)` looks in the directory 'directory' from its parent directory. It does not list the *current* directory. Therefore remove the line `os.chdir(directory)`.

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
    # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
    if os.path.isdir(directory) == False:
        os.mkdir(directory)

    # Create the new file inside of the new directory
    with open(filename, mode="w+") as file:
        pass

    # Return the list of files in the new directory
    return os.listdir(directory)

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the mode in your `open` function

```
import os

def new_directory(directory, filename):
    # Before creating a new directory, check to see if it already exists
    if os.path.isdir(directory) == False:
        os.mkdir(directory)

    # Create the new file inside of the new directory
    os.chdir(directory)
    with open(filename, mode="w+") as file:
        pass

    # Return the list of files in the new directory
    return os.listdir(directory)

print(new_directory("PythonPrograms", "script.py"))
```

Comment: but that's another error... you should try looking for it or at least provide a traceback of the error if you want help.